# Negative-binomial why the answer is 0.288?

Tags: r, negative-binomial-distribution

In a negative-binomial experiment with three independent trials, if I want the probability for 2 successes before the first failure. The probability of each trial is 0.6.

```
dnbinom(c(1), 2, 0.6)
```

in R it gives me 0.288. But why? In my model, the only sequence that can meet my condition is HHT, it's 0.144. Where does the 0.288 come from?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In R the negative-binomial distribution gives the probability of having a certain number of failures before a pre-defined number of successes is achieved.

Therefore

```
dbinom(1, 2, 0.6)
```

gives you the probability of getting one failure, before you get two successes. This is not what you say you want, since the possible sequences include FSS and SFS.

The easiest way to get what you want is to switch the definition of failure and success and then use:

```
dnbinom(2, 1, 0.4)
```